QuarkusRestClientBuilder programmatically doesn't work in AWS Lambda
I have quarkus app and trying to run it as AWS lambda. It's quite simple app with REST client calling some 3rd party services.
myRestClient = QuarkusRestClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                .baseUri(URI.create("https://some.address/"))
                .build(MyRestClient.class);

gradle dependency:
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client'
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client-jackson'

My code is mostly using example written here: https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client#programmatic-client-creation-with-quarkusrestclientbuilder
In aws cloud I'm getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No RestClientBuilderResolver implementation found!"
Also tried change client builder to RestClientBuilder "org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.RestClientBuilder;"
But this one not implementing setter for httpClientOptions which I need to use.

What is it exactly that does not work?
